# Creating a Custom IntStream-like class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, you can write code like the following:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream
    .range(0, 100)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

How can I create a custom `XStream` class? For example, say I have a class that naturally can be ordered, and you can naturally have predecessors and successors to an object. Like:

```
public class PurchaseOrder {
    public long orderNumber;

    public PurchaseOrder(){
        orderNumber = 0L;
    }
}
```

Then, I could have a theoretical PurchaseOrderStream that you can write the following code for:

```
List<PurchaseOrder> list = PurchaseOrderStream
    .range(0, 100)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

How could I go about doing this? Are there any classes or interfaces I need `PurchaseOrderStream` to `extend` / `implement`? I'm not looking for full source code (though that would be nice), but just a push in the right direction.

Comment: If you don’t need the `List` to be explicitly an `ArrayList`, you can simply use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to get a `List` from a stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would just be to use the methods already available. I can't see any reason to reinvent the wheel here.

For example, if you wrote a static method `PurchaseOrder getFromId(long id)` you could just do

```
LongStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(PurchaseOrder::getFromId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

If this isn't short enough, you could write a method

```
public static Stream<PurchaseOrder> range(long low, long high) {
    return LongStream.range(low, high).mapToObj(PurchaseOrder::getFromId);
}
```

Then you could write

```
PurchaseOrder.range(0, 100).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```